# How do I roll over when doing math on an array of integers?

Tags: php, algorithm

So I am trying to do math on an array of integers while enforcing a maximum integer in each piece of the array. Similar to this:

```php
function add($amount) {
  $result = array_reverse([0, 0, 0, 100, 0]);
  $max = 100;

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
    $int = $result[$i];
    $new = $int + $amount;
    $amount = 0;

    while ($new > $max) {
      $new = $new - $max;
      ++$amount;
    }

    $result[$i] = $new;
  }

  return array_reverse($result);
}

add(1); // [0, 0, 0, 100, 1]
add(100); // [0, 0, 0, 100, 100]
add(101); // [0, 0, 1, 0, 100]
```

So what I have above works but it is slow when adding larger integers. I've tried to do this with bitwise shifts and gotten close but I just can't get it to work for some reason. I think I need a third-party perspective. Does anyone have some tips?

Comment: well, one simple optimization: stop the pointless array reversals. you can always run your `for()` loop in a decreasing direction instead: `for($i = count(...); $i > 0; $i--)`

Answer (score 1):

The part that is taking up the majority of the time is the while loop. You are reducing the value down repeatedly until you have a sub-100 value. However, using PHP to loop down like that takes an incredible amount of time (a 12-digit integer clocked in at over 20 seconds on my local machine). Instead, use multiplication and division (along with an if). It is magnitudes faster. The same 12-digit integer took less than a second to complete with this code:

```php
function add($amount) {
    $result = array_reverse([0, 0, 0, 100, 0]);
    $max = 100;

    for ($i = 0, $size = count($result); $i < $size; ++$i) {
        $int = $result[$i];
        $new = $int + $amount;
        $amount = 0;

        if( $new > $max ) {
            $remainder = $new % $max;
            // Amount is new divided by max (subtract 1 if remainder is 0 [see next if])
            $amount = ((int) ($new / $max));
            // If remainder exists, new is the the number of times max goes into new 
            // minus the value of max. Otherwise it is the remainder
            if( $remainder == 0 ) {
                $amount -= 1;
                $new = $new - ((($new / $max) * $max) - $max);
            } else {
                $new = $remainder;
            }
        }

        $result[$i] = $new;
    }

    return array_reverse($result);
}
```

Also note that I moved your `count($result)` call into the variable initialization section of the for loop. When it is inside the expression section it gets executed each time the for loop repeats which can also add to the overall time of executing the function.

Also note that with a large math change like this you may want to assert a range of values you expect to calculate to ensure there are no outliers. I did a small range and they all came out the same but I encourage you to run your own.

Comment: This doesn't handle rollover correctly. If I do `add(400);` I will get `[0, 0, 0, 101, 145]`

Comment: @Dustin - Are you using a different function? I have your function and mine setup and running one after the other. I get `[0, 0, 1, 3, 100]` from both when I run them with 400 as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min($max, $number)` to get `$number` limited to `$max`.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
    $result[$i] = min($max, $result[$i] + $amount);
}
```

Comment: No, it should be `++$i`, just like in the question. Just a typo.